# [SOLVED] Rviz plugin editing

Tags: rviz, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

my question is very simple but I didn't find something similar in the forum. I need to implement 3d motion planning for a tracked vehicle equipped with a laser scanner. I'm using ROS because I want to specify, through Rviz, waypoints during the path execution. I found there is an Rviz plugin called PlantFlagTool, which is really what I need to use. Of course, this plugin needs some changes so I'd like to create a ROS-package and edit the code. Please, can someone explain me how to do this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217285/%5Bsolved%5D-rviz-plugin-editing/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved! I was using catkin, creating a package with rosbuild turned out to be the right choice!

---

Originally posted by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) with karma: 183 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0